# How would i insert a mp4 as a background in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[Need help trying to add the video as a background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D8pOn.png)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `video` tag and change the element size to what you need.
Check this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_fullscreen_video.asp).

Answer (score 0):

you need to import the gif :

```
import bg from "./config/images/bg.gif";

image={CONFIG.SHO_BACKGROUND ? bg : null}
```

Comment: im sorry the gif works im trying to do an mp4. would it be.

import bg from "./config/images/bg.mp4";

video={CONFIG.SHO_BACKGROUND ? bg : null}